# Ошибка отображения логотипа React

Tags: django, reactjs

Всем привет, я запускаю параллельно React на 3000 порту и Django на 8000. Однако поверх моего сайта (8000 порт) высвечивается логотип React и надпись как и на 3000 порту

```
Edit src/App.js and save to reload.

Learn React
```

как мне это исправить? Если я удалю лого из папки static/media, то будет ошибка о невозможности найти это лого. В панеле разработчика в обзоре кода в html присутствует код, который добавляет лого и надпись, однако в VS Code его нет. Если я в файле App.js удалю или закоментрирую код, то тогда и на 3000 порту все пропадет. Я хотел бы, чтобы там оно отображалось. Нужно ли мне написать код для отображения только на 3000 порту или есть еще какой-то способ? Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Бред какой-то, нифига не поняфтно.

Comment: Что не поняфтного? Я запускаю React и Джанго параллельно. В одной вкладке react на 3000 порту, вторая вкладка это Джанго на 8000 с моим проектом. Реакт интегрирован в Джанго. Если на 3000 порту все впорядке, то на 8000 какого-то черта отоборажается поверх моего сайта еще и лого и надпись React с 3000 порта. Вероятно, что из-за интеграции Реакт в Джанго файл App.js выволит логотип не только на 300 порт, но и на 8000. Ну а запрос помощи я описал в вопросе выше